# Flex 4 E4X Filtering By Attributes Has Undefined Variable

Tags: apache-flex, e4x

I have some xml and I am trying to filter it using e4x.  My e4x statement looks like this:

```
model.config.source.fees..fee.(@min<amount).@amount
```

My xml looks liks this:

```
<flex>
  <fees>
    <fee type="credit" min="0.00" max="200.00" amount="6.00"/>
    <fee type="credit" min="200.01" max="370.00" amount="10.00"/>
  </fees>
</flex>
```

When the e4x statement is run, I get an error message: 
**Error #1065: Variable @min is not defined.**

But if I change my statement to model.config.source.fees..fee.@min it will return an xmllist of all the min attribute values, so min is defined, at least in that statement.  Why doesnt the original statement work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `@min<amount` it requires that all fee nodes have the min attribute defined.  It works for your example xml but maybe you were missing `@min` in your other test data.

However, if you use this format:

```
model.config.source.fees..fee.(parseFloat(attribute('min')) < amount).@amount
```

It will handle all nodes whether the attribute is there or not.

Comment: I tried this statement
model.config.source.fees..fee.(attribute('min')==0).@amount
and it is returning an XMLList.  If I do this model.config.source.fees..fee.(attribute('min')==0).@amount.toString();  it is an empty string?

Comment: Similarly, a query akin to "flex.fees.fee.(@type == 'credit')" failed for me with the error "no such variable". Your "attribute('type')" approach fixed that problem as well!